# Is it possible to make child exceed parent' overflow restriction?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, overflow

I am curious to figure out if it's possible to make child div exceed parent div' overflow restriction.

```
<div id="parent" style="overflow: hidden;">
    <div id="child1"></div>
    <div id="child2"></div>
</div>
```

In this case, can i make specifically child1 exceed parent' overflow: hidden, and at the same time keep the overflow restriction for child2? I want to know this, because I'm trying to make a "zoom" effect using transform: scale().

This is a jsfiddle for a bit more advanced example: https://jsfiddle.net/f10vovcg/

I am very curious. Any help is very much appreciated :3 Thanks on advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `position: absolute` to the element, in your case #child1, it will appear even outside parent container because it will be taken out of the flow.
I hope this answers your question.

Comment: I added position: absolute to the child1 element, but it doesn't change the overflow restriction. Please comment if i did something wrong :3

https://jsfiddle.net/f10vovcg/1/